# div background opacity change continuously using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, background, opacity

I want to change div background opacity to 100% to 0% and again 0% to 100% continuously. How would I go about doing this with jQuery?  Here is the markup and CSS I have now.

HTML

```
<div id="sample_div">

</div>
```

CSS

```
#sample_div{
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    background:#65c6ed;
}
```

Comment: In the future (i.e. when all browsers support it), you will be able to do this with just CSS3: http://jsfiddle.net/kaktus621/qxHCu/1/ (this does currently work in Webkit browsers only, therefore no valid solution for your question)

Comment: What is your progress on jQuery code? There is none in jsfiddle.

Comment: Yes. It's empty. I have no idea how to do that. But I know It does can be done using jQuery.

Comment: @ Martin Matysiak: isn't this working in FF ?

Comment: http://buildinternet.com/2009/09/its-a-rainbow-color-changing-text-and-backgrounds/ In this you can see the continual animation in the background.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [`animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function to do that, or [`fadeIn`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) and [`fadeOut`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) which are basically wrappers for it. For example ([live copy](http://jsbin.com/eqavul)):

```
(function() {
    var div = $("selector_for_your_div");

    doFadeIn();

    function doFadeIn() {
        div.fadeIn("slow", doFadeOut);
    }

    function doFadeOut() {
        div.fadeOut("slow", doFadeIn);
    }
})();
```

You might want to put a termination condition in there, though, because otherwise it keeps going forever and that gets old ***fast***. So for instance ([live copy](http://jsbin.com/eqavul/3)):

```
(function() {
    var div = $("#target"),
        countdown = 3;

    doFadeIn();

    function doFadeIn() {
        div.fadeIn("slow", doFadeOut);
    }

    function doFadeOut() {
        if (--countdown >= 0) {
            div.fadeOut("slow", doFadeIn);
        }
    }
})();
```

---

**Update**: You've said below you want to animate the background color. It's the same principle as the above, but jQuery on its own can't animate colors. There's a [color plug-in](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color) that may be able to do it (I haven't tried), and jQuery UI extends `animate` to do it as well. For example ([live copy](http://jsbin.com/eqavul/5)):

```
(function() {
    var div = $("#target");

    doFadeIn();

    function doFadeIn() {
      div.animate({
        backgroundColor: "#eeeeee"
      }, "slow", doFadeOut);
    }

    function doFadeOut() {
        div.animate({
        backgroundColor: "#ffffff"
      }, "slow", doFadeIn);
    }
})();
```

Or with the counter ([live copy](http://jsbin.com/eqavul/6)):

```
(function() {
    var div = $("#target"),
        counter = 3;

    doFadeIn();

    function doFadeIn() {
      div.animate({
        backgroundColor: "#eeeeee"
      }, "slow", doFadeOut);
    }

    function doFadeOut() {
      if (--counter >= 0) {
        div.animate({
          backgroundColor: "#ffffff"
        }, "slow", doFadeIn);
      }
    }
})();
```

Comment: I want to animate only the background color. not the text.

Comment: @Sassi: It's the same principle. I've added an update, see above.